# Why is this parameter dereferencing correctly in this Rust function?

Tags: rust

New to Rust, and still stumbling a bit...I made the below function which works as expected.

If I have parameters such as `n = 18`, `factors = &[3, 6]`, the function will check if any of the "factors" are a multiple of n.

```
fn check_multiple(n: u32, factors: &[u32]) -> bool {
  factors.into_iter().filter(|&y| *y != 0).any(|z| n % z == 0)
}
```

But I'm trying to understand how the referencing and "dereferencing" of "y" in `.filter(|&y| *y != 0)` is working. My understanding is that "&y" is "referential address of y". So shouldn't you have to write it as `filter(|&y| *(&y) != 0)...` to get the correct "dereferencing" of y using the "*"?

Comment: "My understanding is that "&y" is referential address of y", yes you are right, now `y` contains the reference for the value of y. To get the value of `y`, you can dereferencing (`*y`) so you can do comparation on "`y`"

Comment: I generally wouldn't use `into_iter()` on a slice. Just `iter()` does the same thing and is more common, so I'd just stick to it for consistency and to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks for the tip Sven!

Answer (score 2):

[`&[T]::into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) gives an iterator with `Item = &T`. The closure passed to [`Iterator::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) takes an argument of type `&Item`. So in your case, the closure takes an argument of type `&&u32`. In order to be able to compare this argument with 0, you need to get rid of the two levels of reference, which you can do either in the parameter definition, or when you use `y`. So your choices are:

- `|y| **y != 0` dereference both levels on use,
- `|&y| *y != 0` dereference one level in the parameters and one on use,
- `|&&y| y != 0` dereference both levels in the parameters.

Moreover since `u32` implements `Copy`, you can get rid of one level of indirection using [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied):

```
factors.into_iter().copied().filter (|&y| y != 0)
```

---

PS: You can check the type of `y` by adding a deliberately wrong type annotation and looking at the error messages:

```
fn check_multiple(n: u32, factors: &[u32]) -> bool {
   factors.into_iter().filter (|y: ()| y != 0).any (|z| n % z == 0)
}
```

Gives this error message:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments
 --> src/lib.rs:2:23
  |
2 |   factors.into_iter().filter (|y: ()| y != 0).any(|z| n % z == 0)
  |                       ^^^^^^  -------------- found signature of `fn(()) -> _`
  |                       |
  |                       expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r &u32) -> _`
```

Giving the type of the closure argument as: `&'r &u32`